# WHERE NAME LIKE ( A SET OF NAMES )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, select, sql-server-2014

I would like to drop all the jobs related to a set of specific databases.

So I have added all the names into a table variable and I was trying to generate the scripts to drop the jobs.

how can I achieve this?

```
use msdb
go


DECLARE @R TABLE ( NAME VARCHAR(108) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)

INSERT INTO @R(NAME)
SELECT 
'UK15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'US15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'DE15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AT15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'FR15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'EU15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AU15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'UK15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'US15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'DE15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AT15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'FR15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'EU15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AU15SUMSProduct'


SELECT S.* 
FROM SYSJOBS S
WHERE NAME LIKE ( SELECT NAME FROM  @R)
```

something like the select above, I want to see all the jobs that have the database names in them and delete them, for example, like in the script below:

```
exec sp_delete_job @job_name = 'WebFeed UK15SUMMProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
```

Comment: If the search string do not have special characters like `%` then you can simply use `NAME IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Otherwise, you can use `SELECT S.* FROM SYSJOBS S JOIN @R R ON (S.NAME LIKE R.NAME);`. Or `ON (S.NAME LIKE '%' + R.NAME + '%' );`.

Comment: Or is the problem how to dynamically create and execute the `sp_delete` commands?

Comment: @ypercube that does not work, because 'webfeed mydb' like 'mydb' returns false

Comment: I think you missed my edit: `ON (S.NAME LIKE '%' + R.NAME + '%' )`

Comment: @ypercube yes I had missed the edit, but at the end I figured that out, and it is what worked for me, you can see I posted an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the whole query:

```
Declare @job sysname
Declare jobs_cursor Cursor For
    Select S.name 
    From msdb.dbo.SYSJOBS S
    Inner Join (values
        ('UK15SUMMProduct')
        , ('US15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('DE15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('AT15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('FR15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('EU15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('AU15SUMMProduct') 
        , ('UK15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('US15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('DE15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('AT15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('FR15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('EU15SUMSProduct') 
        , ('AU15SUMSProduct')
    ) as n(name) on S.name like '%'+n.name + '%'

Open jobs_cursor
Fetch Next From jobs_cursor into @job

While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    Print 'Remove: '+@job
    exec sp_delete_job @job_name = @job, @delete_unused_schedule = 0
    Fetch Next From jobs_cursor into @job
End

Close jobs_cursor
Deallocate jobs_cursor
```

Part of it is similar to previous answers.

You can replace values(...) by a table variable or a real table.

Answer (score 2):

After your code add this:

```
declare @query varchar(1000), @job_name varchar(1000)

while (select count(*) from @R) > 0
begin
  select top 1 @job_name = [Name] from @R order by [Name]
  select @query = 'exec sp_delete_job @job_name = ''' + @job_name + ''', @delete_unused_schedule = 0'
  exec(@query)
  delete from @R where [Name] = @job_name
end
```

Comment: It won't work witohut a `;` at the end of your exec. Beside, it only works when he already know the name of the job, which is not the case here.

Comment: Oh, that's true but the job names can be found easily enough and inserted into another table at which point my reference to @R can be pointed to that new table.

Answer (score 0):

Try some like that

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)

exec sp_delete_job @job_name = 'WebFeed UK15SUMMProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0

SELECT 'exec sp_delete_job @job_name = '''+S.name+''', @delete_unused_schedule = 0'+char(13)
FROM SYSJOBS S
WHERE NAME LIKE ( SELECT NAME FROM  @R)

exec sp_executeSQL @cmd
```

Comment: I don't know the job name, only the database name. in your example UK15SUMMProduct is fixed, but that is a database name.

Comment: Yes, but the name comes from the select in the variable table

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry, but I don't like the idea or row processing unless really needed.

cursors might not be good for several reasons, [you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server).

I managed to change my select to generate the script I needed:

```
use msdb
go



DECLARE @R TABLE ( NAME VARCHAR(108) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)

INSERT INTO @R(NAME)
SELECT 
'UK15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'US15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'DE15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AT15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'FR15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'EU15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AU15SUMMProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'UK15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'US15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'DE15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AT15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'FR15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'EU15SUMSProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'DE15WINPProduct' UNION ALL SELECT 
'AU15SUMSProduct'



SELECT 'exec sp_delete_job @job_name =' + '''' + s.name + '''' + ', @delete_unused_schedule = 0'
FROM SYSJOBS S
INNER JOIN @R R
ON S.NAME LIKE '%' + R.NAME + '%'
```

The select above produces the result on the picture below:

[image]

and then I copy the rows returned and paste them in the script below, and when run, drops my jobs, but leave my schedules.

```
USE MSDB
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT

exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed AT15SUMMProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed AT15SUMSProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed AU15SUMMProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed AU15SUMSProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed UK15SUMMProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0
exec sp_delete_job @job_name ='WebFeed UK15SUMSProduct', @delete_unused_schedule = 0


COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

Comment: You are right, cursors should be use wisely. However, for what you need and maintenance scripts in general, they are often usefull. I would not use it for table updates in most cases.

Comment: You should probably consider using the [QuoteName function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) instead of concatenating the name if you're going to use this code.

Comment: @Erik I use the quotename function when i need it, I don't see the need in this case. the databases naming follows always the same pattern

Comment: @marcelomiorelli  I just thought I would throw that out there as something to consider.  In my experience it is always the things that I don't suspect which bite me the hardest.  It feels like cheap insurance to me, however you know your data/use cases better than me so you are probably right when you say that it isn't needed.

Comment: why the down vote? it is working fine. The link works, and we're open to discussions and opinions. I find this down vote not fair, whoever has cast it.